# iOS 7 UITableView reload not showing any cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

The table view shows properly at the start, but when I do a reload due to someone typing text in a searchbox, the table does not show the cells. This worked perfectly in iOS 7

This is what I see, everything is called correctly, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called and worked (checked with `NSLog`), but no view is displayed.

There is definitely data, that is not the problem. Has something changed with `UITableView`?

[image]

Comment: Check `cell.contentview.backgroundcolor` property

Comment: yep, something has changed. you need to set the background colour for the cell programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in the way you reuse/allocate your cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath method in case it is not the background colour ?

Comment: No, the problem was due to my own stupid fault, I removed subviews from the table, for a very stupid reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently changed the UIScrollView to a UITableView, and added in some code to remove all the subviews from the UITableView. This kept the headers as shown in the picture, but not the labels and pictures on the cells.